# Morph Animation Between Two Different Objects

Tags: animation, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I'm working on a project and I need to make an animated **morph** between **2 completely different objects**. I tried various videos on YouTube but I was not successful. One of the objects is a cube with Subd and bevel applied. The other is a security icon (a stylized icon with Bevel and subd applied). Is there any way I can switch between these two completely different objects? This is very important to me and I expect your help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show an image of your 2 objects? You could try with shapekeys but it may be easier to do it with another software

Comment: @moonboots I added photos. Which software do you suggest for this. I'm just working Blender.

Comment: In my opinion this one is doable with shapekeys, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morphing you show is doable with shapekeys:

[image]

Here is the basic shape of the object:

[image]

Create a second shapekey and modify the shape this way, also give it a *Bevel* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: It makes perfect sense to do it this way. I will try this. In order for me to apply this method, do both objects have to have the same geometry? So, isn't it possible to transform a different and unrelated geometry into another geometry?

Comment: Yes they need to have the same geometry, it is the exact same mesh

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much :) Have a nice day :)

Comment: You're welcome...........  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to morph between two objects with different topology, you can use the Shrinkwrap modifier.
Add the modifier to object A, specifying object B as the target. Then apply the modifier as a shapekey. Afterwards, you can use that shapekey to make object A look like object B.

Comment: I actually tried that but when I apply shrinkwrap modifier for example different lines appear on the cube and this is evident in the rendering. Thank you for the answer btw. For now I don't need morph anymore :)